# Why can't @babel/parser parse objects?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-parser

When i input an object in [astexplorer](https://astexplorer.net/) like below code, this will get a mistake: `Missing semicolon. (3:9)`, what is that mean? @babel/parser can't parse object correctly?

```js
{
  name: 'test',
  company: 'test company',
}
```

[image: mistake]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is interpreted as a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), not an object literal. However, the contents of the block are not valid statements, hence the error.

If you wrap the code in parenthesis to force the evaluation as an *expression* (and thus as an object literal) it works as expected:

```
({
  name: 'test',
  company: 'test company',
})
```